# How to design interfaces for memory hungry circuits

Tags: circuit-design, vhdl, memory

I'm new to hardware design and one thing I'm struggling with is how to structure the communication between circuits (components). In VHDL you use the `port map` keyword on entities which works well for circuits like simple FSMs, adders, small registers, etc. But what if you want to transmit more sophisticated data, like structs or arrays whose bounds are not static? For example, suppose I'm writing a circuit for sorting integer elements in an array. As there can be millions of integers in the array I cannot have one wire for every bit in every integer. So I need to create a serial interface for transmitting the array elements into and out of the sort circuit. How do I design that? It got to have some control signals so that it can, for example, tell the VHDL code using the sort circuit when the sort is done.

Or maybe this line of thinking is wrong and the sort circuit should operate on data stored in an external memory circuit instead?

In software this would be simple and you would just pass a pointer to the array and an integer denoting the size to a sort function. But I can't come up with what "the equivalent" VHDL entity definition would be.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. You just transmit data in chunks. One clock, one piece of data.

Comment: For example, how large is the chunk? If it is larger than the size of an integer then you would need a method for packing and unpacking it, wouldn't you?

Comment: This is a question of trade-offs. The bigger the chunk, the faster is the transfer, but more hardware is required.

Comment: You have to imagine how it would work in hardware. Imagine you're building it on a breadboard out of logic chips. You have to think about what format the data should be in. Where is the unsorted array coming from, where is the sorted array going?

Comment: Asking for a VHDL equivalent of a pointer is like asking for a C equivalent of a PLL. It just doesn't exist and you have to solve the problem a different way.

Comment: I don't really know. The idea is to make the array sort (and other similar components) relatively generic so that they can be used in many projects.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist maybe start with the one project you're trying to build right now, and worry about the other projects later. Why does it need to sort numbers?

Comment: For sorting numbers you will need memory. Memories have well-established interfaces, which you can look at to get ideas.

Comment: Sorting was just an example. Suppose the circuit encodes mpeg4 video. It also needs to operate on large amounts of data.

Comment: Again, it will operate on memory, which have a defined interface. You just need to use it.

Comment: Then that is what my question is about.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist Well you presumably want the MPEG4 video to come out in a certain order so you can transmit it somewhere. You might make an interface where the MPEG4 video data comes out in order 1 byte per clock cycle, with another wire telling you whether there's actually a byte (if not then the byte wires have nonsense values that should be ignored). The input is probably pixels, 1 pixel per clock cycle (or more if there are too many pixels for that).

Comment: Essential what you are suggesting is a processor that has optimisations for sorting. If you want multiple concurrent sorting operations then you’ll need multiple processors that share the same memory. You get to decide how you share - round robin or some other form of arbitration. You could have multiple memory devices if you wish - its all up to you. An fpga is like a box of Lego - you decide how you put them together.

Answer (score 2):

You have an "external" memory interface either way.

The array in VHDL is referenced by an index, and you pass the index you want to read or write through a `signal`, and pass data back and forth through a `signal` as well.

If the FPGA you are targeting has an embedded RAM component and the access patterns you use can be mapped on that, synthesis will already try to use block RAM, because that takes up significantly fewer resources. From the point of view of the logic element blocks in the fabric, that is an external interface with an address bus and data buses in both directions.

If you make this external memory interface explicit in the code, you can then decide whether you want to connect internal block RAM, or an external RAM -- you'd then pass the address and data lines through a `port`.

For larger applications, you'd use an FPGA with an integrated DDR controller, and your design's memory access `port` would be connected internally to this controller, which then in turn generates the necessary signals to drive the external RAM chips, which (with mid-range to high-end FPGAs) can be on normal DIMMs.

Comment: Do you have any examples or links to guidelines so I can read more about this? Suppose I have multiple data processing units (e.g multiple sort units), wouldn't it increase latency and possibly cause contention if they only have indirect access to the data via a memory interface? I feel like I'm reinventing a wheel here because there must be some "standard patterns" I can use for my circuit designs.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist I don't think there is a standard pattern. You do the thing that works for you. You probably care about performance more than you care about reuse because you only have a limited number of gates.

Comment: Memory access has a latency-vs-speed-vs-size tradeoff. Combinatorial memory gives results in the same cycle, but consumes logic space (so it's limited to a few hundred bytes) and reduces maximum frequency, embedded block RAM gives results in the next cycle, and you have a few kilobytes to a megabyte of it, and DDR has mega- to gigabytes, but a few cycles latency for a command to the active row, and more latency to open and close rows. A typical pattern would be external DDR and cache in block RAM (possibly per-unit L1 and shared L2).